# Set expandLevel for xe:navigator using a theme

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I would like to set the expandLevel property for several extension libary navigators using a theme. I can set expandable and expandEffect but I can not get expandLevel to work. I am using the following in my theme:

```
 <!-- Navigator -->
 <control>
    <name>Outline.Navigator</name>
    <property type="boolean">
        <name>expandable</name>
        <value>true</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>expandEffect</name>
        <value>wipe</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>expandLevel</name>
        <value>#{0}</value> 
    </property>
</control>
```

I have also tried using `<value>0</value>` which also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Booleans need to be passed as EL, just like numbers. Pass the value of the expandable property as #{true}, otherwise it will try to assign a String value.

Comment: Tim, the expandable property works just fine. It's the expandLevel property I can't get to work :-)

Comment: Might be another timing issue, then. If the contents need to be evaluated prior to the render phase, the theme may be correctly setting the attribute, but it's being ignored. This is why you can't set attributes like the value of a repeat via a theme.